# Detect browser or tab close in Angular 12 and use MatDialog for confirmation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-routing

I am using the below code to check of the browser tab is closed or not, this works with windows dialog, however, I want to put MatDialog here for confirmation

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    return false;
  }
```

I tried the below code,but it doesn't work

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    this.iDialogData.title = 'Unsaved changes';
    this.iDialogData.bodyMessage = 'If you leave this page, any unsaved changes will be lost.';
    this.iDialogData.cancelBtnText = 'Cancel';
    this.iDialogData.mainbtnText = 'Leave page';
    const dialogRef = this.openDialog();

    return dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(map(result => {
      if (result !== undefined)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }));
  }
```

Comment: I don't think browsers can deal with observables. but you could always return `false` and emit the same event after the confirmation

Comment: Can you please show an example

Comment: Can you try by debugging this in the dev tools? (add word "debugger" into the code and run). By debugging, i want to check if this.openDialog() method is called or not.

Comment: @AshishDeora yes it has been called, but UI is not loaded on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate this direction:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    if (this.canClose) {
        return true;
    }

    this.iDialogData.title = 'Unsaved changes';
    this.iDialogData.bodyMessage = 'If you leave this page, any unsaved changes will be lost.';
    this.iDialogData.cancelBtnText = 'Cancel';
    this.iDialogData.mainbtnText = 'Leave page';
    const dialogRef = this.openDialog();

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if(result) { 
           this.canClose = true;
           // re-emit the event
        }
    });
    return false;
  }
```